# Prime too close to f in Garamond Math

Tags: kerning

Here

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}   % luatex
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmathfont{Garamond Math}

\begin{document}
Test \(\mathrm{Df'_2}\).
\end{document}
```

the prime is too close to the f.  I suppose this is an error in Garamond
Math.  What's the right way to fix it?  (I'd prefer one that doesn't
require typing something different every time.)

(Df'_2 is the name of a definition.  `Df` should therefore be typeset as
ordinary text, not with the extra spacing produced by `\symup`.)

Comment: I prefer to write like this `\(\mathrm{Df\,'_2}\)`.

Comment: In `unicode-math`, `\mathZZ` commands are for “words”, not for single letters, where `\symZZ` should be used.

Answer (score 7):

Use \symrm instead of \mathrm. I also prefer to put only the letters in the argument - even if doesn't make a difference here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}   % luatex
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmathfont{Garamond Math}

\begin{document}
Test \(\mathrm{Df}'_2\).

Test \(\symrm{Df}'_2\).

Test \(\symrm{Df'_2}\).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this result in too much space between D and f?

Comment: +1: Is \symrm a standard command? Didn't use it before.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner well the standard name is \symup and \symrm is an alias, but I always forget this.